# SQL Trigger behavior - Joins on child tables does not fetch results/values

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-insert

I have a parent table P1 which has few child tables C1, C2, C3.

I wrote an "After" trigger on P1 which makes a query joining the child tables.

The insert into the parent table is marked with Begin Tran and End Tran as follows.

Begin Tran

Insert into P1

Insert Into C1

Insert Into C2

...

Commit Tran

My problem is, the query written inside the "Insert" trigger on the Parent table P1 has Joins to the child tables. but no results are obtained when the trigger fires.

Is it because of the Inserts marked with Begin and End transaction statements being not commited by the time the trigger on P1 fires.?

Or is it because by the time the trigger is fired, the child tables has not got their parent references resolved? meaning the inserts to the child tables are placed after the insert to the parent table.?

When i pulled just the "query" out of the trigger and ran in a separate query window fetches me the results. Could not figure out the exact reason for this behavior.

Someone please throw some light on. Let me know if you need more details please.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code for the triggers and the definition of the tables.  [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)